# Is there a way to force a parameter to be passed by value instead of ref in C# like you can in VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net

Having just answered a question about calling VB6 methods with parentheses, I remembered that you could force `ByRef` parameter values to be passed `ByVal`. Researching, I found this still works in VB.NET.

However, I cannot find anything similar in C# that allows for this. This past year I have had to reference a lot of VB.NET class libraries that take in `ByRef` for no good reason (trust me, I checked). This has forced me to set properties on objects to local variables in order to pass them in. Not a major issue, but not very clean if you ask me.

I am wondering if there is a syntactical solution that I am not aware of.

As an example of my current pattern that I would like to avoid:

```
var tempSomeObject = BarObject.FooProperty;
SomeVb6BusinessLogicMethod(ref tempSomeObject);
// Continue to do work and set other temp objects due to ref constraint
```

In VB6 and VB.NET, you can just do the following to force ByVal on a ByRef parameter.

```
SomeVb6BusinessLogicMethod((BarObject.FooProperty)) 'Note the extra parens
```

**EDIT:** I am not asking about the differences between ByRef and ByVal. I am asking if C# has a similar way to force a ByRef parameter to be pass ByVal. See this MSDN doc of the VB.NET functionality.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chy4288y.aspx

Comment: In C# param type decides that right?

Comment: What happens to the property if the method tries to modify it? I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work in VB.NET...

Comment: Somehow I doubt it, sounds like a goofy backwards compatibility thing that it is available in VB.NET

Comment: @Cameron It works as if it was `ByVal`. Basically it is only modified inside the method, the outside property is not modified.

Comment: @TyCobb: So the object is being copied behind the scenes? How is the copy made?

Comment: @Cameron I assume, it is being copied behind the scenes. How exactly, I am not sure.

Comment: @Cameron: It's just an assignment to a temporary, just like the C# code posted - all VB is doing is assigning to a hidden temporary.

Comment: @Dave: Ah, of course. Thanks. I feel silly now :-)

Comment: @Cameron: Don't feel silly - VB is silly for using hidden fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to explicitly copy the value to a new variable and pass in the new variable by reference, as you showed in your question.  There is no syntactic sugar in C# that would allow the compiler to perform this copy on your behalf as is done in VB.

Comment: Lame. Was really hoping I could learn a new trick. Oh well. That makes sense why I couldn't find an answer for this anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: @TyCobb Just remembered that there's a relevant new feature to C# 6.0 in this regard, although it's not a *particularly* huge improvement here.

Comment: Declaration expressions were recently shelved: https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Oh nice! That's still cleaner than the current way of handling it. EDIT : @DaveDoknjas Booo!

Comment: There no exotic 'copy' happening in the VB code - just a plain old assignment to a hidden temporary.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas That's exactly what I mean by a copy.  It's copying the value of the variable to a new (hidden) variable.  Nothing exotic about it.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I understand that, but I love sugar.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas thanks for pointing out that the feature was pulled; edited.

Comment: You can create an exact copy of a class by serializing it and then deserializing it.  I have created extension methods in the past that create an automated copy in that manner.  It is much slower than manually copying fields, but less code to write and will not as easily break if fields are later added to your class.  Note that you have to choose an appropriate serializer (e.g. some only serialize public members).

Comment: @EricJ.: But remember that all VB is doing is an assignment to a hidden local variable - the best C# equivalent is not complex, it's just an assignment to a visible local variable.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: So is VB copying the address of the variable (just creating a new alias to the same place in memory), and not copying the object itself?  ByVal, passing by value, means that a copy is passed in (e.g. placed on the stack).  Is that a copy of the address pointing to the memory backing the object instance, or a copy of the actual object?

Comment: @EricJ. It's a copy of the value of the variable.  In this case, the value of the variable is a reference to an object, so a copy of the reference is created.  Were the object to be a value type then it's value would be the actual value, and in such cases a copy of *that* would be made.

Comment: @EricJ.: It's just exactly the same as what happens in any other assignment.  If it's a reference type, then the hidden temporary is a copy of the same 'address', if it's a value type, the hidden temporary is just a copy of the value.